# Orbeon XForms round-when-formatting="true"

Tags: orbeon, xforms, rounding

I would like to ask if there is an option for the `round-when-formatting="true"` parameter combined with `digits-after-decimal="0"` parameter in Orbeon XForms to use Traditional rounding.
(23.6->24)(22.8->23)(23.2->23)

In the [documentation section](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/number.html) I see that it uses half to even rounding method.

`round-when-formatting="true"` is ideal for using rounding only in the view section, because I want the rounding only in the view, the values for the calculations in the bindings must be unrounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there is no such option. I agree that using `round-to-even()` might not be the right choice. Possibly, this was used because this function in XPath 2 allows specifying a precision, while the `round()` function doesn't. However, this is fixed wth XPath 3. Either way, I entered [issue #3226](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3226).

Comment: No, see discussion in #3226.